# Error en WSGI usando digital ocean con flask y ubuntu 18.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, servidor, flask

Estoy configurando un app flask de prueba en digital ocean con ubuntu 18.04.

Siguo la guia de digital ocean.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 ,todo funciona hasta el paso de sudo systemctl status.. genera el siguiente error  alguna idea?

```
    ● webfolio.service - uWSGI instance to serve webfolio
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-02-22 14:04:02 UTC; 5h 7min
 Main PID: 10951 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Feb 22 18:14:12 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:14:12 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:14:12 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:16:19 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:18:40 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:18:40 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 18:18:43 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 19:11:07 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 19:11:07 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
Feb 22 19:11:10 flask systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webfolio.service:4: Missin
```

**wsgi**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve webfolio
After=network.target
systemctl status webfolio.service
[Service]
User=user560
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user560/webfolio
Environment=/home/user560/webfolio/webfolio/bin
ExecStart=/home/user560/webfolio/webfolio/bin/uwsgi --ini webfolio.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**ESTRUCTURA DE DIRECTORIO**

```
webfolio:
|--static  
|--templates  
|-- webfolio ---+Este es VIRTUALENV  
|-- webfolio.ini
|-- requirements.txt  
|-webfolio.py  
|--wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el archivo /home/myuser/web/web/bin/uwsgi existe, lo mas probable es que no encuentre el archivo web.ini, entonces lo mas recomendable es que utilices la ruta absoluta del archivo web.ini, algo como:

```
ExecStart=/home/myuser/web/web/bin/uwsgi --ini /ruta/absoluta/web.ini
```

donde:
*/ruta/absoluta/* es la carpeta donde se ubica el archivo, puedes obtenerla con el comando **pwd**

Comment: Hey, use `ExecStart=/home/myuser/web/web/bin/uwsgi --ini /root/web/web.ini`  y reviso con  `sudo systemctl status` web:: error  `/etc/systemd/system/web.service:4: Missing '='  ` @lennhv

Comment: Podrías mostrame todo tu archivo de configuració web.service?

Comment: claro este es:
```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve web
After=network.target
systemctl status web.service
[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/web
Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/web/web/bin"
ExecStart=/home/myuser/web/web/bin/uwsgi --ini web.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

```

Comment: El directorio principal se llama web, el virtualenv tambien lo llame web,
(web)--adentro esta :|--static |-|--templates |-- |web |-->este es  VIRTUALENV | aca los archivos en el mismo nivel de web -->--web.ini - web.py - wsgi.py

Comment: Intenta quitarle las comillas en Enviroment, en los ejemplos de la documentación no se utilizan. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files, observa el ejemplo del punto 2.

Comment: listo,despues de revisado sigue enviando el mismo error /etc/systemd/system/web.service:4: Missing '=', inclusive elimine el PATH de enviroment y sigue igual miratndo tambien muestra: Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)

Comment: Puedes hacer algo distinto y mejor por cuestiones de seguridad, supongo que instalaste uwsgi con el administrador de paquetes. Si es así, deberias de tener ya un servicio uwsgo configurado, prueba con systemctl status uwsgi.  El servicio debe estar detenido. Tu aplicación puede correo como un vassal si configuras al UWSGI en modo Emperor, que desde mi punto de vista es lo mas recomendable. Inenta verificar lo que te comento y te voy guaindo en el proceso.

Comment: listo, al ejecutar el `systemctl status uwsgi` la consola dice: **Unit uwsgi.service could not be found.
** l estoy listo ,para seguir indicaciones, --y si lo instale por el administrador de paquetes

Comment: Por favor, actualiza en la pregunta la configuración tal como la tienes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90096/discussion-between-developer-and-lennhv).